# MKMapView regionDidChange never been called when zoomin/out

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I created a new UIViewController and added a MKMapView. The `regionDidChange` never been called when zoom in/out. But it's been called when I pan or tap on the map. What could be the possible cause? Anybody have the same issue?

By the way, I'm using iOS 12.

Comment: Post what you have done, to help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
mapKitView.delegate = self
```

add this line

Comment: Of course I added this. You didn't look at my post carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the method of delegate and then check the property - is zoomable.
If you can tell more information, that's cool.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same issue as the one being described.  I added the line mapView.delegate = self in my viewDidLoad() section and all of a sudden my app now works properly.  I just wanted to add this comment to anyone else who may have a similar issue but not know where to add the line of code.  Thanks Bagusflyer for posting this item, and thanks Kartik for posting an answer that has worked in my case :).

Comment: The only tiny snippet I will add is make sure that the mapKitView.delegate = self comes after you have setup the CLLocation calls otherwise the app may terminate with a nil found error.  Likewise Thank You to Bagusflyer for posting the question and Thank You Kartik for posting the answer that worked for me too :)